# How to find Max Date in List<Object>?

Tags: java, collections

Consider a class `User`

```
public class User{
  int userId;
  String name;
  Date date;
}
```

Now I have a `List<User>` of size 20, how can I find the **max date** in the list without using manual iterator?

Comment: Your question is unclear for me. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Sort your list using a custom comparator and take the first result.

Comment: What do you mean by "manual iterator". Does `Collections.max(yourList, yourComparator)` counts as "manual"?

Comment: I tried Using Comparator! It works fine! but i am looking some thing like lambdaj approach but not lambdaj!!

Comment: If you are asking us to recommend you a tool or library then your question is off-topic on SO (take a look at point 5 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) )

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Since you are asking for lambdas, you can use the following syntax with Java 8:

```
Date maxDate = list.stream().map(u -> u.date).max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

or, if you have a getter for the date:

```
Date maxDate = list.stream().map(User::getDate).max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

Comment: Thank you, also did the job for me! This solution avoids the use of a `Comparator`, which can be annoying because it not recognizes the type of objects in the `Stream`.

Comment: You need to use map first in order to get an stream of dates

Comment: It's a safer way to use the orElse(null) then .get();

Comment: @zeroke in general I agree that one shouldn't call `get` directly - in this case however, if you know that the list is not empty then you'er safe. So it's context dependent I suppose.

Comment: I found this by searching for a similar problem, but I would need in your example the user with the max date. For that case there is another nice thing: 
`Optional<User> user = users.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(User::getDate));`

Comment: If you want the object with the max date and not just the date itself you can do:

`User user = Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(User::getDate))`

Comment: I get "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" from Date::compareTo

Comment: @SteveWaters Works fine here: https://ideone.com/lz5lNt - you may want to ask a separate question with more details about the code you are running.

Answer (score 13):

A small improvement from the accepted answer is to do the null check and also get full object.

```
public class DateComparator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(new Employee(1, "name1", addDays(new Date(), 1)));
    employees.add(new Employee(2, "name2", addDays(new Date(), 3)));
    employees.add(new Employee(3, "name3", addDays(new Date(), 6)));
    employees.add(new Employee(4, "name4", null));
    employees.add(new Employee(5, "name5", addDays(new Date(), 4)));
    employees.add(new Employee(6, "name6", addDays(new Date(), 5)));
    System.out.println(employees);
    Date maxDate = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getJoiningDate() != null).map(Employee::getJoiningDate).max(Date::compareTo).get();
    System.out.println(format.format(maxDate));
    //Comparator<Employee> comparator = (p1, p2) -> p1.getJoiningDate().compareTo(p2.getJoiningDate());
    Comparator<Employee> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getJoiningDate);
    Employee maxDatedEmploye = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getJoiningDate() != null).max(comparator).get();
    System.out.println(" maxDatedEmploye : " + maxDatedEmploye);

    Employee minDatedEmployee = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getJoiningDate() != null).min(comparator).get();
    System.out.println(" minDatedEmployee : " + minDatedEmployee);

}

public static Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); // minus number would decrement the days
    return cal.getTime();
}
}
```

You would get below results :

```
 [Employee [empId=1, empName=name1, joiningDate=Wed Mar 21 13:33:09 EDT 2018],
Employee [empId=2, empName=name2, joiningDate=Fri Mar 23 13:33:09 EDT 2018],
Employee [empId=3, empName=name3, joiningDate=Mon Mar 26 13:33:09 EDT 2018],
Employee [empId=4, empName=name4, joiningDate=null],
Employee [empId=5, empName=name5, joiningDate=Sat Mar 24 13:33:09 EDT 2018],
Employee [empId=6, empName=name6, joiningDate=Sun Mar 25 13:33:09 EDT 2018]
]
2018-03-26
 maxDatedEmploye : Employee [empId=3, empName=name3, joiningDate=Mon Mar 26 13:33:09 EDT 2018]

 minDatedEmployee : Employee [empId=1, empName=name1, joiningDate=Wed Mar 21 13:33:09 EDT 2018]
```

Update : What if list itself is empty ?

```
        Date maxDate = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getJoiningDate() != null).map(Employee::getJoiningDate).max(Date::compareTo).orElse(new Date());
    System.out.println(format.format(maxDate));
    Comparator<Employee> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getJoiningDate);
    Employee maxDatedEmploye = employees.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getJoiningDate() != null).max(comparator).orElse(null);
    System.out.println(" maxDatedEmploye : " + maxDatedEmploye);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Comparator<User> cmp = new Comparator<User>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(User user1, User user2) {
        return user1.date.compareTo(user2.date);
    }
};

Collections.max(list, cmp);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
LocalDate maxDate = dates.stream()
                            .max( Comparator.comparing( LocalDate::toEpochDay ) )
                            .get();

LocalDate minDate = dates.stream()
                            .min( Comparator.comparing( LocalDate::toEpochDay ) )
                            .get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use Kotlin!

```kotlin
val list = listOf(user1, user2, user3)
val maxDate = list.maxBy { it.date }?.date
```

Answer (score 0):

## troubleshooting-friendly style

You should not call .get() directly. Optional<>, that `Stream::max` returns, was designed to benefit from .orElse... inline handling.

> If you are sure your arguments have their size of 2+:

```
list.stream()
    .map(u -> u.date)
    .max(Date::compareTo)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 'list' to be of size: >= 2. Was: 0"));
```

> If you support empty lists, then return some default value, for example:

```
list.stream()
    .map(u -> u.date)
    .max(Date::compareTo)
    .orElse(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
```

CREDITS to: @JimmyGeers, @assylias from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

## self-explanatory style

```
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
...

    list.stream()
        .map(User::getDate)
        .max(naturalOrder())
        .orElse(null)          // replace with .orElseThrow() is the list cannot be empty
```