# The min non-null LocalDateTime of a list using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know how to get the min `LocalDateTime` of a list thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20996009/270143

e.g. `LocalDateTime minLdt = list.stream().map(u -> u.getMyLocalDateTime()).min(LocalDateTime::compareTo).get();`

My problem is slightly different though...

1. I would like the min `LocalDateTime` that is not `null`
2. or `null` if they are all `null`

How would I go about doing that in a concise way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
Optional<LocalDateTime> op = list.stream()
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

And the `absent` value would indicate that there are only nulls in your List (or your List is empty)

Comment: in my case an empty list will never occur - due to checks beforehand

Comment: simple and effectively.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, maybe?

```
LocalDateTime minDate = list.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(u -> u.date)
    .min(LocalDateTime::compareTo)
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: ah I guess I can just use the `Optional` being empty to indicate `null`

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak probably `orElse(null)` instead of `get`, since the OP wants a `null` when all are null in the List

Comment: Just a side note, when the element type implement `Comparable`, it’s preferable to use the existing `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of creating a new comparator via `ComparableType::compareTo`…